# set -e overwrites parameter variable($@) in bash script

Tags: linux, bash

I have a script test.sh

```
#/!bin/bash
set -e
trap errorhandler ERR

errorhandler(){
    status=$?
    trap - ERR
    exit $status
}

echo "$@"

exit 0
```

when I call `sh test.sh 'Hey'` it will print `-e` instead of `Hey`.

My work around is surround `set -e` with backticks but dont know if it still works as intended

Another workaround is to store it in a variable in the first line but I would like my `set -e` in the first line for one obvious reason (handling an error).

Is there a clever way to do this? Like "Hey don't touch my $@" command.

Comment: Run `bash test.sh 'Hey'` instead of `sh test.sh 'Hey'`.  That worked for me.

Comment: tried it, it does not work for me, but thanks.

Comment: Strange, I tried your code as is with both sh and bash and it worked fine on the Mac.  On Linux it worked with bash but not sh, where I got `trap: ERR: bad trap`.  I am using bash 4 on both.  What version are you using?  One other possibly minor thing: your shebang should prolly be `#!/bin/bash` (note the inital slash).  Probably won't effect what you are seeing, but just an FYI.

Comment: @RayToal `#/bin/bash` is not the answer but yes its the proper way. I edited the question. check my answer. thanks for the help, appreciate it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Got it! `-e` and `–e` notice the dash. the first one is correct.

Lesson learned. Do not copy code directly from html.

Comment: Oh, the left one is about 4 pixels shorter that the right one? How do you even get that char to appear? Thanks.

Comment: I copied the set –e from one website, and pasted it to vim. One perfect example is the dash before my name